# electrum doesn't start with new ubuntu 22.04. It needs libfuse

Tags: electrum

I have new installation of ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
When tried to start electrum I get the following error:

```
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

I've tried to install libfuse

```
sudo apt install libfuse
```

However, it seems that this package doesn't exist. How to get libfuse installed?

Answer (score 1):

libfuse library contained in libfuse2 package. It might be installed using the following command

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```